# Начальная страница сайта, Modx revo

Tags: modx

Переместил на другой хостинг сайт на modx, который на прошлом хостинге работал правильно и вместо корректного вывода получил вывод файла index.php:
Все файлы config - там поменял пути, названия БД и тд, три раза проверил. Помогите пожалуйста.

```html
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of MODX Revolution.
 *
 * Copyright (c) MODX, LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * For complete copyright and license information, see the COPYRIGHT and LICENSE
 * files found in the top-level directory of this distribution.
 */

$tstart= microtime(true);

/* define this as true in another entry file, then include this file to simply access the API
 * without executing the MODX request handler */
if (!defined('MODX_API_MODE')) {
    define('MODX_API_MODE', false);
}

/* include custom core config and define core path */
@include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.core.php');
if (!defined('MODX_CORE_PATH')) define('MODX_CORE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/core/');

/* include the modX class */
if (!@include_once (MODX_CORE_PATH . "model/modx/modx.class.php")) {
    $errorMessage = 'Site temporarily unavailable';
    @include(MODX_CORE_PATH . 'error/unavailable.include.php');
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 503 Service Unavailable');
    echo "<html><title>Error 503: Site temporarily unavailable</title><body><h1>Error 503</h1><p>{$errorMessage}</p></body></html>";
    exit();
}

/* start output buffering */
ob_start();

/* Create an instance of the modX class */
$modx= new modX();
if (!is_object($modx) || !($modx instanceof modX)) {
    ob_get_level() && @ob_end_flush();
    $errorMessage = '<a href="setup/">MODX not installed. Install now?</a>';
    @include(MODX_CORE_PATH . 'error/unavailable.include.php');
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 503 Service Unavailable');
    echo "<html><title>Error 503: Site temporarily unavailable</title><body><h1>Error 503</h1><p>{$errorMessage}</p></body></html>";
    exit();
}

/* Set the actual start time */
$modx->startTime= $tstart;

/* Initialize the default 'web' context */
$modx->initialize('web');

/* execute the request handler */
if (!MODX_API_MODE) {
    $modx->handleRequest();
}
```

Comment: На вашем хостинге в тарифе вообще присутствует услуга "PHP"?

Comment: да, конечно, я кстати пробовал сменить версию php и апач, не помогает

Comment: а `phpinfo()` работает?

Comment: вручную менять - всё равно что-то пропустишь. Лучше загугли перенос сайта на модексе, есть подробные инструкции же.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема не в MODX,если бы с ним были проблемы -получили бы ошибку, например, 503. Похоже на проблему конфигурации веб-сервера, что у апача указано в DirectoryIndex? Document_root из вывода phpinfo() совпадает с тем, где лежат каталоги сайта?